# Custom Menu for all Google Documents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-apps-script-addon

Is it possible to create "custom menu" for all of my Google Documents ?

All i need is when ever a new Document/Spreadsheet is created, and the work is done then the user should be capable of invoking a Custom Menu.

So i would like to display the "Custom Menu" for all of my documents.﻿

Answer (score 1):

this is possible by building an add-on. first make the menu:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

then see the official documentation from Google which explains in detail how to publish your add-on.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/